# Finding the maximum of a harmonic function

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations

> Suppose that $u$ is a harmonic function in the disk $D = \{ r < 1 \}$ such that $u|_{r=1} = \theta^2$ for $-\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$. Without finding the solution $u$:
>
> a.) Find the maximum value of $u$ in $\overline{D}$.
>
> b.)  Find $u(0,0)$, the value of $u$ at the origin.

Attempted solution a.) - By the maximum principle, the maximum is achieved on $\partial D$. On $\partial D$, the function $u(1,0)$ can be handled as a single variable function. The critical points of the function satisfy $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} = 2\theta = 0$$
That happens at $\theta = 0$. As $u(1,0) = 0$ the maximum value is not defined.

Attempted solution b.) - The value of $u$ at the origin can be found by the mean value property:
\begin{align*}
u(0,0) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\theta^2 d\theta\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\frac{\theta^2}{3} \Big|_0^{2\pi}  \right]\\
&= \frac{4}{3}\pi^2
\end{align*}

I want to know if these solutions are correct. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean the maximum is not defined? If you believe the maximum occurs at $(1,0)$ shouldn't you say the maximum is $0$? Regardless, be careful - by using $\theta$ as a coordinate you're modelling the circle as an interval, so the maximum isn't necessarily a critical point - it could occur at an endpoint.

Comment: "The maximum value is not defined" what did you mean by this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a), the maximum value of $\theta^2$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$ is $\pi^2$, occurring at the endpoints.  Note that $\theta = \pi$ and $\theta =-\pi$ both correspond to the same point $(-1,0)$.

Your answer to (b) is correct.

Comment: Could you expand on your solution to a.) I don't fully understand

Comment: Also if you could look at this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2351690/solving-an-inhomogenous-system-pde I have been working on it for sometime with little results

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 Can you just picture the graph of the function $x^2$ for $-\pi \le x \le \pi$?  Where does it take its maximum value?

Comment: @ErickWong $\pi$?

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 You seem pretty unsure... Is there something about maximization of a function of a single variable that's unfamiliar to you?

Comment: @ErickWong take derivative set to 0 find critical point plug it back into function

Comment: @ErickWong Am I missing something here?

Comment: Could you please expand your answer to a.) so that I can accept your answer and be done with this question?

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 It is not very clear why the answer needs to be expanded.  Part a) is very simply a one-variable maximization problem, you should be specific about what you don't understand.  To me it seems like you just need to review your intro calculus course on finding the maximum of a function on an interval, but I'm not sure what part you are confused by.  Multiple people have asked you why you claim the maximum is undefined, but you haven't explained yourself.